# MVC.NET how to secure submitting forms after edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit

When I want to submit a form to save an edited record, I should pass its Id to controller. Then a client (or attacker) may change some information (e.g. this Id) on the form that I don't want to be changed. I can create a hashed hidden field to check that read-only fields have not been changed and verify it when it is posted to controller. 
Is there any other good practice for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: AntiForgeryToken in-built functionality of .NET MVC, which can verify the token and request, You should try that it will help you out for sure. Let me know still anything required. Thank you!!!

Comment: Anti-Forgery Token can not do anything if an attacker changes for example the Id and send it back to the same site. It's just to check for cross site forgery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode data you want to protect with server side algorithm, that way that view receives encoded data only. When user passed the form to controller you decode data and check for validity. Also remember to implement not only client side validation, but also server side validation for your model.

Answer (score 1):

**AntiForgeryToken:**  A great feature in ASP.NET MVC is the AntiForgeryToken. This Generates a hidden form field (anti-forgery token) that is validated when the form is submitted. The anti-forgery token can be used to help protect your application against cross-site request forgery

> .cshtml Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

> Controller Code

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Your Code
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Anti-Forgery Token can not do anything if an attacker changes for example the Id and send it back to the same site. It's just to check for cross site forgery.